# Older ios app is deleted automatically when a new version is available on MDM (MobileIron), but the updated app is not automatically installled

Tags: ios, mdm, mobileiron

My enterprise application has been distributed using `MDM (MobileIron)`.First time installation was not an issue.

However, when a newer version of application is put on `MDM`, the older version that is installed on `iPad` automatically gets deleted without any warning. The user then has to install it manually again. This is unusual.. right?

I am updating the build version (`CFBundleVersion`) for each newer version. I am not changing CFBundleIdentifier.

What can be the problem? is there an `MDM` setting that I have missed to check?

Answer (score 1):

That is unusual.

When we update our MDM build, the app is automatically updated on all iPads unless the app is currently in the foreground.  If it is in the foreground the user is prompted to install the new version or cancel for now.

We update both the CFBundleVersion and the CFBundleShortVersionString.

How do your users install the app manually?